# How can we make a TIMER with (RESET) functionality in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am very new to shell scripting, I have googled many things for this problem. But cannot find a perfect solution to it.

Problem is: It's a log monitoring code with "ERROR", Pattern 
How can we make a TIMER in unix scripting. Support I have a timer of 5 minutes, and time keep on decreasing every 1 second. So I want to reset again the timer to 5 minute on certain condition (say $FREQUENCY of ERROR occurrence is greater then say for ex2).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATTERN='ERROR'
TIMER=300
FREQUENCY=2

while true;
do grep -i $PATTERN logfile > tmp_log

while [ $TIMER -gt 0 ]
do
  sleep 1 &
  printf "  $TIMER \r" &
  TIMER=$[$TIMER-1];
  wait

done

if [[ $(wc -l <tmp_log) -ge $FREQUENCY ]]
        then
            TIMER=300
            echo $TIMER
fi

 sleep $TIMER
done
```

Comment: You need to reset when the frequency of error crosses a certain value. Correct me?

Comment: @AshishK Yes you are Right .When it goes above certain frequency than reset it

Comment: do you also need to clear the tmp_log after reset? As i can see it would be very much required.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN='ERROR'
TIMER=300
FREQUENCY=2

while true
do
        while [ $TIMER -gt 0 ]
        do
                sleep 1
                TIMER=$((TIMER - 1))
                grep -i $PATTERN logfile > tmp_log
                count=`wc -l tmp_log | awk '{ print $1 }'`
                if [ $count -gt $FREQUENCY ]
                then
                        TIMER=300
                fi
        done
        break
done
```

This is good going for your case.

Comment: do you also need to clear the tmp_log after reset? As i can see it would be very much required.

Comment: Yeah, but i guess i will do that....But is "timer" & "TIMER" different ?

Comment: No, sorry for that ..Both are same..I have corrected it :)

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly ??

Comment: If you are waiting for 5 minutes for a file (logfile) to consist of 'ERROR' pattern less than the given number of times (here frequency), this will work. However the timer would be reinitialized to 5 minutes everytime once the count reaches greater than frequency. Therefore I was asking whether the count is to be reinitialized every time the timer is reinitialized?

Comment: You have an outer `while true` loop, but the last statement in its body is `break` and there is no early continuation.  This loop is useless, as it will execute only once.

Comment: Also, every second you grep `tmp_log`, but this file never gets written to after the initial `grep` (which itself executes only once because the outer loop is executed only once.  The result will be the same every time, so if your condition is met on the `count` vs `frequency` test you will always reset the timer.

Comment: @fred , break at the last does not execute the loop once. It is used to terminate the infinite while if the number of `'ERROR'` matches is below `$frequency` during the alloted time frame. The scope iterates inside `while [ $TIMER -gt 0 ]` after entering while true loop.

Comment: I had assumed the logfile from which the pattern is to be grepped is ready and a single command would extract all the `'ERROR'` patterns at once. However after you pointed this out, I feel the grep statement should be inside the 2nd while loop with `>` to keep checking on a real-time if the logfile is getting updated during the process.

Comment: @AshishK  Look hard at your loops, you will see that as soon as the first iteration of the outer loop finishes, the `break` causes the loop to terminate, guaranteeing it will never actually loop.

Comment: @AshishK  You way of approaching this problem is very inefficient.  You should monitor the log file (e.g. with `tail -F`) and handle its ouput line by line, while in a separate process you would `sleep 300`.  The two processes would communicate with signals (`kill`) to indicate reset or termination.  It is a very different way to program a solution, but it would avoid polling and reduce timer drift (due to the time it takes to execute your statements, 300 iterations will take more time than 300 seconds).

Comment: @fred you are correct, as soon as it finishes, which is here after 300 seconds (if the number of ERROR in the file is less than $frequency). I am running the above code on my system by placing a text file with two error counts. The scripts remains active for 300 seconds.

Comment: @fred thanks for pointing this out. `tail -f` would be a better approach. I will try doing this problem by the approach you suggested. However the context of the question was yet not clear. I tried coding the script to what I understood. However break thing which you pointed out confused me as it was not breaking the first loop after one iteration.